# Trying to read a local text file in html page using ajax

Tags: ajax

Tried this code to read data from a local text file. 
But I don't know why this is not working. 
Could someone help me with this problem. I can see in most of the answers in stackoverflow, they say that this is working, but this is not working for me. do I have to install anything for this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","sample.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AJAX won't read files from the local file system. You have to get a server.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No. You must have an IIS or apache for example. Or register on a free hosting service.

Comment: You can load local files if your page is local.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `XMLHttpRequest` will not read files from the local filesystem (otherwise malicious websites could read files on your desktop!). Here are some solutions:

1. Install a server on `127.0.0.1`. For a quick and dirty solution, you can use Python's [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) or the Node.js [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) package. For production, use [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com) or [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/).
2. Put your files on a web host, such as [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can only read local files on the server side without user interaction. If you want to read a client side file, you have to use an html interaction element like:

```
<input type="file" id="openselect" />
```

Otherwise, if your file is on the server side, you could use something like:

```
function getdatafromfile(filename)  {
// Read annotation file. Example : %timeinstant \t %value \n
// Return an array of string
var arraydata
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: filename,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(csv) {arraydata = $.csv.toArrays(csv,{separator:'\t'}); }
      });
return arraydata;}
```